# get_serving_url via remote_api_shell.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, console

I want to record all the current urls for images I'm storing using appengine. However, when using appengine's remote_api_shell.py console, I'm unable to use the get_serving_url function even though I have PIL set up correctly on my local machine.

```
>>> c.image_blob
<google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo object at 0x16f0150>
>>> from google.appengine.api.images import get_serving_url
>>> get_serving_url(c.image_blob)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 1231, in get_serving_url
    response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 308, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 178, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 198, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    raise pickle.loads(response_pb.exception())
CallNotFoundError
```

For now I just made a view to do the dirty work for me on appengine production machines, but I feel like there should be a way of calling the get_serving_url function via the console.

Comment: App Engine doesn't have a "manage.py console". Are you talking about Django?

Comment: Just requested the feature from appengine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remote_api` doesn't currently have a mapping for the `get_serving_url` API call. You can add it yourself by importing [remote_api_services](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_services.py) and adding it to the dict in the appropriate place, but either way you should definitely [file a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry).

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate how to do this for the newbie?